# "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __aligned_malloc" при сборке ruby

Tags: ruby, компиляция

Захожу `C:\Users\Aydar\Desktop\ruby-2.2.0\win32 запускаю configure.bat` пишу `nmake`

Вывод

```
...

gc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __aligned_malloc

gc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __aligned_free

miniruby.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl' : return code '0x2'

Stop.
```

Comment: Andrii Tereshchenko wrote:

kk kk wrote:

G:\ruby-2.1.2\win32>nmake

You should follow README.win32 and configure and nmake from parent folder, not from win32.

I.e. inside G:\ruby-2.1.2 call win32\configure.bat and then do nmake from same source code root. Not from win32.

Comment: C:\Users\Aydar\Desktop\ruby2.2.0>C:\Users\Aydar\Desktop\ruby2.2.0\win32\configure.bat
Creating verconf.mk
Creating Makefile.new
"type `nmake' to make ruby."

C:\Users\Aydar\Desktop\ruby-2.2.0>nmake

...

gc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __aligned_malloc
gc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __aligned_free
miniruby.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это скорее куда-нибудь в рассылку вопрос. Если он нужен для работы могу посоветовать для Windows [rubyinstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) или установку через Cygwin. Оба варианта приемлемые и рабочие.